# how to find a Minimum Salary In sql?

Tags: sql

my database reads only first integer of the salary according to the first integer it will give the result
example:

```
salary
3000
2000
10000
```

in this  minimum is 2000 but it will display the 10000 as a minimum salary
because its reads only first integer of the value

```
select min(Salary) as Minimum_Salary 
from tbl_Employee
```

and it will give the result is 10000 as a minimum salary

Comment: What [tag:rdbms] are you using? And what datatype are you using to store the salary?

Comment: What is the datatype of `salary` ? If it is of `varchar` type then 10000 will be minimum value.  Which `DBMS` you are using ?

Comment: thank u now i get answer  @Prdp

Comment: @Dynamo -Post the working query as answer and mark it as answer to help future readers

Answer (score 1):

Change column type from "varchar" to "int"

Answer (score 0):

You are storing the salary as a string rather than as a number.  You can change the type of the column, something like:

```
alter table tbl_Employee alter column salary money;
```

However, that does not work in all databases.

When calculating the minimum, you can convert to a numeric type:

```
select min(cast(salary as numeric(18, 2))
from tbl_Employee;
```